# Strange PHP string error

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This is a very very weird bug that happens randomly.  So I will try to explain this as best as I can.  I'm trying to diminish the code substantially to pinpoint the problem without having to reference a framework, nor deal with 500 lines of code outside of the framework - so I will try and come back and update this question when I do.  OK, so here we go.

So basically say I'm taking a string in a function and preg_replace like so:

```
$table = '/something';
print $table;
$table = preg_replace("@^(/)@",'prefix_',$table);
print $table;
```

The output will look something like

```
...
/something - prefix_something
/something - prefix_something
/something - /something

You have an error in you sql query... blah blah somewhere around SELECT * FROM /something
```

What happens is that after rolling through the code, this simply stops working and the sql errors out.  What's more strange is that if I start commenting out code outside the function it then works.  I put that code back in, it breaks.

I tried recoding this by `substr($var,0,1)` and var_dumping the variable.  After a few rounds it returns a `bool(false)` value even though $var is in fact a string.  It's very very strange.  Has anybody run into this before?  Is this a PHP bug?  It's looking like it to me.

-- EDIT --

Example:

```
foreach ( $user as $id => $user ) {
  get_data("/table_name","*", "user_id = '$id'");
}


#in the function $_table_ holds "/table_name"
    $_table_ = trim($_table_);
    $tmp = explode(',', $_table_);
    $tables = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $c => $n) {
        $n = trim($n);
        $a = substr($n, 0, 1);
        $b = substr($n, 1);
        if ($a == false) {
            var_dump($n);
            $a = substr($n, 0, 1);
            var_dump($b);
            var_dump($a);
        }
        if ($a == '/') { etc...
```

Output:

```
string(11) "/table_name" string(10) "table_name" bool(false)
```

If I switch to the original preg_replace functionality, it simply does not preg_replace and the same thing happens "/table_name" is return rather then "prefix_table_name"  and this happens randomly.  Meaning it will work on the string it broke on if I comment code out outside of the function that is seemingly unrelated.

--- **SOLUTION** ----

I found out that it has to do with string to array conversion in another function that caused this strange error.

Basically a function was expecting a `null` or `array()` value and instead a number was passed.  We have notices turned off, so I turned them on and started fixing all the notices and warnings and that's how I found this strange bug.  Now exactly what the inner workings are that created the problem is unknown to me.  However I can define the symptom as a string assignment problem that would occur at some other place in the code which we caught when it wouldn't reassign the $table variable with the new preg_replace value which is detailed above.  Now you know.  The function looks something similar to this:

```
function format_something($one, $two, $three = array()){
    if ($three['something'] == 'Y') {
    /** etc... */
}
...
format_something('one','two',3);
```

After a while in a loop this type of conversion started having problems randomly in the code.

Comment: Is it possible that you have `/something/somethingelse` as the string, because your regex will only replace the first instance.

Comment: Nope.  That's not it.  As you can see from the output, first is the original string, second is the string after manipulation.  Basically the the variables is not reassigning to the preg_replace value, because I can then preg_replace later on in the code with a new value and it will in fact work.  It's very very very strange.

Comment: We should see a complete code example, that fails.

Comment: @Erik I would provide a code example but it's functional and around 500 lines.  I figured out the problem though, solution is above.

Answer (score 4):

[substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) doesn't always return a string. If it can't find the substring, it returns false.

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the extracted part of string, or FALSE on failure or an empty string.

You should test for this condition and var_dump the string you are searching to see what it contains in such cases.

Comment: Yes, I think var_dumping a bool(false) from substr on a string is saying something.  Shouldn't substr($var,0,1) ALWAYS return '/' if the string will ALWAYS be '/something'?  If the $var is '/something' and it returns a bool(false) from substr($var,0,1) then there's something else going on here... am I correct?

Comment: In theory yes, but perhaps it's encountering an empty string?

Comment: Sorry, pushed enter.  - If I var_dump both the variable and substr I get a string value and length > 1 for the variable, and then the substr value is bool(false).  If that was a natural occurrence of PHP then I think that would be a seriously flawed programming language.

Comment: This sounds like some more concrete examples are in order, I'm not sure how to help without knowing exactly the content of the string, and being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes definitely.  I'm trying to do this now.  I can say that yes in fact there is always a string in the variable and at some point it breaks, not because there is no string, but because of some other crazy thing.  If I comment out something else completely unrelated to that perceived problem, either that problem happens on a different string OR it runs fine.  It's freaking weird.

Comment: If you happen to figure it out, please post; would be most curious as to what causes this.

Comment: @JYelton yeah I actually found out the problem.  It was random and strange because it was dealing with string to array conversion situation in another funciton.  See we have notices turned off, so I turned them on and started fixing these notices and warnings and I found out that this function (that is not related to the code above) was expecting a null or array value and the original coder threw a numeric through and it messed up assignments or something later on in the execution of the script and caused this bazzare problem which showed itself when a query would error out.